# Create contingency tablel based on users input - Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

For two categorical variables inside a dataframe I want to compute the fisher test based on the user selection for the variables, specific factors of these variables (and also filtering by another column).

For this, I need to obtain the contingency table, and then apply the fisher.test function.

Just to visualize it, here is how it can be done in R base:

```
library(vcd)
library(dplyr)

a <- Arthritis %>%
  dplyr::filter(Treatment == "Treated") %>%
  dplyr::filter(Improved == "Some") %>%
  count() %>%
  as.numeric()
b <- Arthritis %>%
  dplyr::filter(Treatment == "Treated") %>%
  dplyr::filter(Improved != "Some") %>%
  count() %>%
  as.numeric()
c <- Arthritis %>%
  dplyr::filter(Treatment == "Placebo") %>%
  dplyr::filter(Improved == "Some") %>%
  count() %>%
  as.numeric()
d <- Arthritis %>%
  dplyr::filter(Treatment == "Placebo") %>%
  dplyr::filter(Improved != "Some") %>%
  count() %>%
  as.numeric()

data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(a,b,c,d), nrow= 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

fisher.test(data)
```

For the RepEx below I just want to obtain the contingency table.

You can see it clearly, but just to explain a little bit:

- First we create the UI, where we allow the user to select several variables (var1, var2, biomarker) and then the factors for the statistics.
- Then we update this variables based on user input
- We create the contingency table (dataframe) based on the users selection

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)

# Data
library(vcd)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)

# Stats cohen.d wilcox.test
library(effsize)


not_sel <- "Not selected"


## UI
ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    title = "Plotter",
    titlePanel("Plotter"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        title = "Inputs",
        fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
        selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),                        # X variable num_var_1
        selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)), 
        selectInput("biomarker", "Select biomarker", choices = c(not_sel)), uiOutput("factor"),
        uiOutput("Xgroup1"),uiOutput("Xgroup2"), uiOutput("Ygroup1"), uiOutput("Ygroup2"),
        br(),
        actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
         tabPanel(
            title = "Statistics",
            verbatimTextOutput("test")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)



## Server

server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data. We allow the user to input the data that they want 
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$xlsx_input)
    #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    #read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    Arthritis
  })
  
  # We update the choices available for each of the variables
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "biomarker", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  biomarker <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$biomarker)
  
  ## Update variables
  
  # Factor for the biomarker
  output$factor <- renderUI({
    req(input$biomarker, data_input())
    if (input$biomarker != not_sel) {
      b <- unique(data_input()[[input$biomarker]])
      pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_factors',
                  label = 'Select factors',
                  choices = c(b[1:length(b)]), selected=b[1], multiple = TRUE,
                  # choices = c("NONE",b[1:length(b)]), selected="NONE", If we want "NONE" to appear as the first option
                  # multiple = TRUE,  ##  if you wish to select multiple factor values; then deselect NONE
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
    }
  })
  
  output$Xgroup1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_1, data_input())
    c <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Xgroup1',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(c[1:length(c)]), selected=c[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  
  output$Xgroup2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_1, data_input())
    d <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Xgroup2',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(d[1:length(d)]), selected=d[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  
  output$Ygroup1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_2, data_input())
    c <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_2]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Ygroup1',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(c[1:length(c)]), selected=c[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  output$Ygroup2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_2, data_input())
    c <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_2]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Ygroup1',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(c[1:length(c)]), selected=c[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  


  ##############################################################################
  
  data_stats <- reactive({
    req(data_input(), input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2, input$biomarker, input$selected_factors) 
    # We filter by biomarker in case user selected, otherwise data_input() remains the same
    if (input$biomarker != "Not Selected") df <- data_input()[data_input()[[input$biomarker]] %in% input$selected_factors,]
    else df <- data_input()
    a <- df %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$Xgroup1) %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$Ygroup1) %>%
      count()
    b <- df %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$Xgroup2) %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$Ygroup1) %>%
      count()
    c <- df %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$Xgroup1) %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$Ygroup2) %>%
      count()
    d <- df %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$Xgroup2) %>%
      dplyr:filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$Ygroup2) %>%
      count()
    
    data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(a,b,c,d), nrow= 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
  })
  
  output$test <- renderPrint(data_stats())
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this app is not generating any results.

Comment: Please note that `input$Xgroup1` should actually be `input$selected_Xgroup1`, and so on...

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @YBS, however it's not working. output$test is not printing anything, nut no error message appears neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors.  First, the inputID for `Ygroup2` was still `selected_Ygroup1`. Second, `dplyr:filter()` will not reference the `dplyr` package as it should be `dplyr::filter()` - that is double colon. Lastly, your variables should not be `input$Xgroup1` but actually be `input$selected_Xgroup1`, and so on. Also, it is better to have eventReactive instead of reactive.  Try this

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjqui)

# Data
library(vcd)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)

# Stats cohen.d wilcox.test
library(effsize)


not_sel <- "Not selected"


## UI
ui <- navbarPage(
  tabPanel(
    title = "Plotter",
    titlePanel("Plotter"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        title = "Inputs",
        fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
        selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),                        # X variable num_var_1
        selectInput("num_var_2", "Variable Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)), 
        selectInput("biomarker", "Select biomarker", choices = c(not_sel)), uiOutput("factor"),
        uiOutput("Xgroup1"),uiOutput("Xgroup2"), uiOutput("Ygroup1"), uiOutput("Ygroup2"),
        br(),
        actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(
            title = "Statistics",
            verbatimTextOutput("test")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


## Server

server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data. We allow the user to input the data that they want 
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$xlsx_input)
    #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    #read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    Arthritis
  })
  
  # We update the choices available for each of the variables
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "biomarker", choices = choices)
  })
  
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  biomarker <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$biomarker)
  
  ## Update variables
  
  # Factor for the biomarker
  output$factor <- renderUI({
    req(input$biomarker, data_input())
    if (input$biomarker != not_sel) {
      b <- unique(data_input()[[input$biomarker]])
      pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_factors',
                  label = 'Select factors',
                  choices = c(b[1:length(b)]), selected=b[1], multiple = TRUE,
                  # choices = c("NONE",b[1:length(b)]), selected="NONE", If we want "NONE" to appear as the first option
                  # multiple = TRUE,  ##  if you wish to select multiple factor values; then deselect NONE
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
    }
  })
  
  output$Xgroup1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_1, data_input())
    c <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Xgroup1',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(c[1:length(c)]), selected=c[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  
  output$Xgroup2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_1, data_input())
    d <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_1]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Xgroup2',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(d[1:length(d)]), selected=d[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  
  output$Ygroup1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_2, data_input())
    c <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_2]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Ygroup1',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(c[1:length(c)]), selected=c[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  output$Ygroup2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_2, data_input())
    c <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_2]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_Ygroup2',
                label = 'Select group for statistics',
                choices = c(c[1:length(c)]), selected=c[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  
  
  ##############################################################################
  
  data_stats <- eventReactive(input$run_button, {
    req(data_input(), input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2, input$biomarker, input$selected_factors) 
    req(input$selected_Xgroup1,input$selected_Xgroup2,input$selected_Ygroup1,input$selected_Ygroup2)
    # We filter by biomarker in case user selected, otherwise data_input() remains the same
    if (input$biomarker != "Not Selected") df <- data_input()[data_input()[[input$biomarker]] %in% input$selected_factors,]
    else df <- data_input()
    a <- df %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$selected_Xgroup1) %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$selected_Ygroup1) %>%
      count()
    b <- df %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$selected_Xgroup2) %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$selected_Ygroup1) %>%
      count()
    c <- df %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$selected_Xgroup1) %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$selected_Ygroup2) %>%
      count()
    d <- df %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_1]] %in% input$selected_Xgroup2) %>%
      dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$selected_Ygroup2) %>%
      count()
    
    data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(a,b,c,d), nrow= 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
    m <- matrix(unlist(data), 2)
    fisher.test(m)
  })
  
  output$test <- renderPrint(data_stats())
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @YBS. You have helped me a lot, since this is not the first question I ask. However, have you tried to run the code? At least in mine nothing happens, no error appears, but no information appear either, not for  `output$test <- renderPrint(data_stats())`, not for the fisher.test function after I add it

Comment: OK, I will post the output I get.

Comment: Please try the updated code for fisher test.

Comment: Thanks @YBS. However, do you know why is it not possible to obtain the statistic without selecting Biomarker first?

Comment: Remove `input$biomarker` from `req()` in the `eventReactive()`.